# Is there a way to break-up a regular expression (Regex) with multiple patterns onto multiple rows?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\s+(\d{1,2})\,\s+(\d{4})|(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This is used two find two specific date patterns:

1. MMM(M), dd yyyy
2. mm/dd/yyyy

To make the code more readable and easier to debug, I would like to break the Regex patterns onto multiple rows, like:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\s+(\d{1,2})\,\s+(\d{4})
                                |(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Using the above doesn't work. If I try to store the patterns in two strings, then C# complains about the backslashes.

Is it possible to breakup multiple regex patterns onto multiple rows so that they are easier to read/debug?

Comment: Use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works - thank you. If you post as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: _"If I try to store the patterns in two strings, then C# complains about the backslashes."_ Not if you put `@` before each string

Comment: if you store it in multiple strings make sure you mark each string as a litteral with the @, ie `@"myRegex" + @"myRegex"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SublimText and multi select (ctrl + d on "|" char)

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(Jan(?:uary)?|"+
                    "Feb(?:ruary)?|"+
                    "Mar(?:ch)?|"+
                    "Apr(?:il)?|"+
                    "May|"+
                    "Jun(?:e)?|"+
                    "Jul(?:y)?|"+
                    "Aug(?:ust)?|"+
                    "Sep(?:tember)?|"+
                    "Oct(?:ober)?|"+
                    "Nov(?:ember)?|"+
                    "Dec(?:ember)?)"+
                    @"\s+(\d{1,2})\,\s+(\d{4})|"+
                    @"(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```